# How to get intensity value of each pixel in java similar to the one in matlab?

Tags: java, image

I need java code to get the intensity value of each pixel in an image(not the rgb value). Using matlab tool, i can get the intensity value of each pixel which ranges from 0 to 255. when i give an image of 512*512, i get 512*512 intensity value (ranging from 0 to 255). is there any code to incorporate the same in java. The following code give rgb value in binary so for white color it gives -1 whereas in matlab the same would be represented by 255.Is there any inbuilt function in java to do so?

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\C2C\\Image.jpg"));
  for(int i = 0; i < 704; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 604; j++)
    {
        img[i][j] = image.getRGB(i, j);
        System.out.println(image.getRGB(i,j));
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: How is the intensity value defined in Matlab? You can just take the average of the R, G and B values, since RGB values already have a curve applied to them, but perhaps Matlab applies another curve to it; you need to figure that out.

Comment: From your question I think you know how to get the values for Red, Green and Blue. To calculate the intensity just do:
`int gray = (r + g + b) / 3;`

Comment: You haven't shown any code that gives `-1` for white (unless you mean you're showing the RGB value, and the alpha channel value is also FF, because RGB is in the lower 24 bits of the `int`). You've just shown code that copies the RGB values from the image into a (presumably) `int[]`. How are you splitting the RGB `int` into its R, G and B components? Where you you averaging the RGB values?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt you answered my question by asking more questions. Thank you.

Comment: @schugDev Thanks as well !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are one step away from getting what you want.

Currently you can get a pixel's rgb value with

```
int rgb = BufferedImage.getRGB(i ,j);
```

which gives you an integer.

Using this rgb value to construct a Color object:

```
Color c = new Color(rgb);
int red = c.getRed();           //get intensity of red (0 - 255)
int green = c.getGreen();    //get intensity of green (0 - 255)
int blue = c.getBlue();        //gey intensity of blue (0 - 255)
```